# BDE to ADO conversion in DELPHI 5

Tags: delphi, ado, bde

I have an application in my company. I want to convert it from BDE to ADO Connection.
I searched almost everywhere, I did not find any good answer.
The AIM IS
Convert that BDE connection to ADO connection but we need to use TQuery component to fetch data from database.
So, it will look like we are using BDE but internally it uses ADO Connection.
So, please answer this question you cant imagine, how thankful i will be.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi @DAVID I have an application which was build in delphi 5. And for connecting to database, it uses BDE( Borland Database Engine). So I want changes in my application, so that it will use ADO (ActiveX Data Object) Connection.. how can i do this..??

Comment: That's too broad. You need to be familiar with both technologies, and then you need to do some programming. When you get stuck on a specific, ask a question here.

Comment: Easy.  You just re-code your application to use TAdo components rather than BDE ones.  I don't know why you have bothered to ask this from a new account when I have explained to you more than once that you cannot mix BDE components with a TAdoConnection.

Comment: Thanks @David I will try to do that.

Comment: @MartynA sir, this is my task in our company, may be you have given answer to someone else, because there are number of interns in our company.
And one more thing, if it was not possible they woudnt have given to me
. There must be way, re-coding is easy and simple, like copy and paste.

Comment: No. You are going to need to think and work hard and understand. It needs skill and expertise. It needs knowledge and understanding of both frameworks. Programming is not cut and paste. Well, not if you want to succeed. If you think you can succeed with that approach you are in the wrong profession.

Comment: David sir, i am not talking about copy paste.
What I am thinking is in TDatabse component, if somehow we can set the database Alias to ADO connection and then,
we can override some functions of TQuery component and add our own properties to our Custom Component to use ADO.
Then may be its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... if somehow we can set the database Alias to ADO connection ...

Just take a look at the source code of Delphi's BDE and ADO support (in e.g. DBTables.Pas and ADOInt.Pas + ADODB.Pas and you will soon see that they are as different as chalk and cheese.

You have no hope of e.g. using a TAdoConnection via the BDE from a Delphi app.

What you *could* do is do move your data to an ADO database (e.g. MS Sql Server) and then create a) a System DSN to connect to the ADO db via ODBC and then b) set up a BDE Alias that uses the BDE alias and c) change your existing BDE app to use the new alias instead of the one it currently uses.  That way, you can continue using your existing app to access the ADO version of the data via TTable, TQuery etc and develop a parallel TAdo-component based equivalent at your leisure.

You could easily try this out using the traditional Delphi MastApp or "Fish Facts" demo application and data.  Getting your existing BDE app to access an ADO-compatible copy of your data via an ODBC alias should not be more than a day's work even if you have never done it before.  Actually converting your BDE app to ADO would likely take rather longer, though.

There are countless examples of different ways of copying BDE (e.g. Paradox) data to ADO data on the internet.  Try looking at a few.

Comment: Yeah I looked the source code of BDE and ADO. It was like many things connected to each other, sharing data and calling many functions and procedures.
But yeah Thank you Martyn sir very much for your suggestion and valuable time. I was looking for approach like this. I will try to do that.
Thank you once again :)